# eclipse, wtp and tomcat configuration for source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant

I have a java project in eclipse which is having jar file reference of other projects.
Now, I have removed those jar files and added projects in eclipse, no compilation error in eclipse. I have configured Tomcat server in eclipse.
But server doesn't get loaded when i add project instead of jar files.

I have observed following path in eclipse workspace:

```
<<Eclipse IDE workspace>>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ESW\WEB-INF
```

under WEB-INF folder, jar files and class files are located. All jar files are loaded to 'jar' but under classes folder no class files are present at this directory. here i am expecting class files of the project which i have added in source folder instead of jar files. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the **Deployment Assembly** option (Project Properties ---> Deployment Assembly ) to configure which files to be deployed to the WTP Tomcat  . Before eclipse 3.5 or before , this option is called something likes **J2EE Module Dependencies**

[image]

Deploy path is relative to the your `<<Eclipse IDE workspace>>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ESW\`  while source path is relative to your project folder.

Comment: i have done this. Under ESW i find only lib folder and no classes are found. inside library i found the jar file which i doesn't want to be there and it has to go for classes folder. one more issue i found is spring loading problem for place holder ie one of proerty is not getting loaded